# Change color of specific listview item

Tags: android, android-listview

I need to change the text color of some specific items of the listview.

```
lstdetails = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstdetails);

ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
    Details.this, details_list,
    R.layout.Details, new String[] {
            "lecture_key", "date",
            "total_lect_int", "attendance" },
    new int[] { R.id.tvKey, R.id.tvdate,
            R.id.tvtotallect, R.id.tvattendance });

lstdetails.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Text color needs to be changed on the basis of the value of **R.id.tvattendance**

The above snippet is in the **onPostExecute** function of the class extending **AsyncTask**

Comment: write custom adapter for the same

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement custom adapter, extend from `BaseAdapter` class, and change color in `getView` method

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement custom adapter
You can view the full implementation i did in this opensource project

[Customadapter in Fragment](https://github.com/smart-electro/Android_app/blob/master/MyEV/src/com/irobotlabs/myev/FragmentTab2.java)

```
  private class listviewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


   @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

      int value= listAdapter.get(position); // or whatever data type is your value

      if (value==0){
            //change color of the textview at runtime here
        }else{

            //or some other color
        }

     }




   }


i am using this inside a fragment and it works perfectly
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is two option for you to accomplish it.

1. **Normal Way** : Using a custom adapter and customize each row as you wish. For this way, please take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8166497/1841194)
2. **Ugly Way!**  : Use `mListView.getFirstVisiblePosition()` and `mListView.getLastVisiblePosition()` as well as `mListView.getChildAt(...)` to obtain a reference to that row and then customize it as you wish.